# How to configure kubernetes (microk8s) to use local docker images?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microk8s

I've build docker image locally:

```
docker build -t backend -f backend.docker
```

Now I want to create deployment with it:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: backend
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend
        image: backend
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent # This should be by default so
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

`kubectl apply -f file_provided_above.yaml` works, but then I have following pods statuses:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                   READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
backend-deployment-66cff7d4c6-gwbzf    0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          18s
```

Before that it was `ErrImagePull`. So, my question is, how to tell it to use local docker images? Somewhere on the internet I read that I need to build images using `microk8s.docker` but it [seems to be removed](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/382).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found docs on how to use private registry: https://microk8s.io/docs/working

First it needs to be enabled:

```
microk8s.enable registry
```

Then images pushed to registry:

```
docker tag backend localhost:32000/backend
docker push localhost:32000/backend
```

And then in above config `image: backend` needs to be replaced with `image: localhost:32000/backend`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56515971/microk8s-pushing-image-to-local-registry