# microk8s pulling image, stuck in ContainerCreating state

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, microk8s

As described in the [doc](https://microk8s.io/docs/working) (based [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55549522/how-to-configure-kubernetes-microk8s-to-use-local-docker-images)).

I am on Ubuntu as a host OS.

```
docker --version
```

> Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77

```
microk8s 1.14/beta
```

---

Enable local registry for `microk2s`:

```
microk8s.enable registry
```

Checking:

```
watch microk8s.kubectl get all --all-namespaces
```

> container-registry   pod/registry-577986746b-v8xqc 1/1     Running            0          36m

Then:

Edit:

```
sudo vim /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

Add this content:

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["127.0.0.1:32000"]
}
```

Restart:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Double checking, see if  insecure is applied:

```
docker info | grep -A 2 Insecure
```

> ```
> Insecure Registries:
>  127.0.0.1:32000
>  127.0.0.0/8
> WARNING: No swap limit support
> ```

Tag:

```
docker tag my-registry/my-services/my-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT 127.0.0.1:32000/my-service
```

Checking:

```
docker images
```

> 127.0.0.1:32000/my-service latest e68f8a7e4675 19 hours ago 540MB

Pushing:

```
docker push 127.0.01:32000/my-service
```

I see my image here: http://127.0.0.1:32000/v2/_catalog

In `deployment-local.yml` I have, now the proper image:

```
...spec:
  containers:
    - name: my-service-backend
      image: 127.0.0.1:32000/my-service
      imagePullPolicy: Always ...
```

Then applying:

```
envsubst < ./.local/deployment-local.yml | microk8s.kubectl apply -f -
```

I see: `ContainerCreating`

By: `microk8s.kubectl describe pods my-service-deployment-f85d5dcd5-cmd5`

In the Events section:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                 From                     Message
  ----     ------     ----                ----                     -------
  Normal   Scheduled  107s                default-scheduler        Successfully assigned default/my-service-deployment-f85d5dcd5-z75tr to my-desktop
  Normal   Pulling    25s (x4 over 106s)  kubelet, my-desktop  Pulling image "127.0.0.1:32000/my-service"
  Warning  Failed     25s (x4 over 106s)  kubelet, my-desktop  Failed to pull image "127.0.0.1:32000/my-service": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to resolve image "127.0.0.1:32000/my-service:latest": no available registry endpoint: failed to do request: Head https://127.0.0.1:32000/v2/my-service/manifests/latest: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
  Warning  Failed     25s (x4 over 106s)  kubelet, my-desktop  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    10s (x5 over 105s)  kubelet, my-desktop  Back-off pulling image "127.0.0.1:32000/my-service"
  Warning  Failed     10s (x5 over 105s)  kubelet, my-desktop  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Seems like my-service is stuck there.

**Q: What could be the reason?**

**UPDATE:**
 changing all to `localhost` helped, meaning I could see now in the browser: http://localhost:32000/v2/_catalog .

```
{"repositories":["my-service"]}
```

But it worked only in Firefox.. weird. In chrome is pending..

Still:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                    From                    Message
  ----     ------          ----                   ----                    -------
  Normal   Scheduled       161m                   default-scheduler       Successfully assigned default/my-service-deployment-6d4c5587df-72xvd to my-laptop
  Normal   Pulling         160m (x4 over 161m)    kubelet, my-laptop  Pulling image "localhost/my-service"
  Warning  Failed          160m (x4 over 161m)    kubelet, my-laptop  Failed to pull image "localhost/my-service": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to resolve image "localhost/my-service:latest": no available registry endpoint: failed to do request: Head https://localhost/v2/my-service/manifests/latest: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Failed          160m (x4 over 161m)    kubelet, my-laptop  Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed          159m (x6 over 161m)    kubelet, my-laptop  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff         131m (x132 over 161m)  kubelet, my-laptop  Back-off pulling image "localhost/my-service"
  Normal   SandboxChanged  22m                    kubelet, my-laptop  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal   Pulling         21m (x4 over 22m)      kubelet, my-laptop  Pulling image "localhost/my-service"
  Warning  Failed          21m (x4 over 22m)      kubelet, my-laptop  Failed to pull image "localhost/my-service": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to resolve image "localhost/my-service:latest": no available registry endpoint: failed to do request: Head https://localhost/v2/my-service/manifests/latest: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Failed          21m (x4 over 22m)      kubelet, my-laptop  Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed          20m (x6 over 22m)      kubelet, my-laptop  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff         2m22s (x87 over 22m)   kubelet, my-laptop  Back-off pulling image "localhost/my-service"
```

Seems it tries to connect by https..

--

Ok.. had to add the port for the yml image: part. will accept the answer below. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your whole `deployment-local.yml`, output of `curl http://127.0.0.1:32000/v2/_catalog` and output of `cat /var/snap/microk8s/current/args/containerd-template.toml | grep endpoint` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In microk8s is a big different between **localhost** and **127.0.0.1**. As you mentioned, you were based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55549522/how-to-configure-kubernetes-microk8s-to-use-local-docker-images) Stack case and there user were using **localhost**.

The main issue here is error `no available registry endpoint: failed to do request:`. It means microk8s cannot find endpoint.

If you will run commend below, you will have the same output

```
$ cat /var/snap/microk8s/current/args/containerd-template.toml | grep endpoint

endpoint = ["https://registry-1.docker.io"]
endpoint = ["http://localhost:32000"]
```

As you see in microk8s endpoint is **localhost** not 127.0.0.1

Please change image in deployment-local.yaml

```
...spec:
  containers:
    - name: my-service-backend
      image: localhost/my-service
      imagePullPolicy: Always ...
```

Let me know if you will occur any other issues.

In my case I did not need tag and push image again with localhost, only change in YAML was required.

Comment: thanks for the help. will accept your answer. The answer was: use 'localhost' as you said + image: localhost:32000/my-service (port is important too, not sure how it worked without the port for you). + I put an update for my question. FYI.
Thanks.

Comment: plus, I think the fact that I switched to `microk8s 1.14/beta` helped. with the very begginging, I have been using the localhost, but I had to switch to 127.0.0.1 to avoid another issue - being able to push images.

Answer (score 2):

I also needed to comment out following line in the /etc/hosts (Ubuntu 18.04)

```
::1 localhost ip6-localhost
```

It seems that microk8s isn't capable of IPv6.

Comment: I did not have localhost alias bind to any ipv6 IP but only with 127.0.0.1 but still, it does not work. Any thoughts on this?